# MigLayout, aligning all components at center of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

how can I align my components at JPanel at the center of JFrame.

Here are my codes and what i got

[image: a busy cat]

I want like this

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](https://i.hizliresim.com/VVGB6Z.jpg))</sub>

**MainFrame**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {


private static MainFrame instance = new MainFrame();

public static MainFrame getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public static void switchToPanel(JPanel p) {
    getInstance().setContentPane(p);
    getInstance().validate();
}

private MainFrame() {
    setTitle("FavMovies");
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainFrame.switchToPanel(new LoginPanel());
}
}
```

**LoginPanel**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;



public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {

// PROPERTIES

private JTextField inputUsername;
private JPasswordField inputPassword;

// CONSTRUCTOR

public LoginPanel() {

    setSize(400,400);

    // COMPONENTS

    inputUsername = new JTextField(10);
    inputPassword = new JPasswordField(10);
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    JButton createButton = new JButton( "Create User");

    setLayout(new MigLayout());

    // first row
    add(new JLabel( "Username: "));
    add(inputUsername, "wrap 5");

    // second row
    add(new JLabel( "Password: "));
    add(inputPassword, "wrap 10");

    // final row        
    add(loginButton);
    add(createButton); 


}

}
```

I hope I could explain :( I hope I could explain    :( I hope I could explain    :( I hope I could explain    :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridBagLayout` will center components automatically. So set the layout of the frame to use a `GridBagLayout` and then just add your login panel to the frame:

```
//getInstance().setContentPane(p);
getInstance().setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
getInstance().add(p);
```

Edit:

> However, when i resize it, i was able to see loginPanel at center.

It looks like you are adding a component to a visible GUI. So you need to manually invoke the layout manager and repaint the component.

```
getInstance().validate();
getInstance().revalidate();
getInstance().repaint();
```

The structure of your code is really complicated. You should read the Swing tutorial for better examples and you won't have this problem. Maybe start with the `LabelDemo` from [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).

If you need the ability to swap panels, then take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on `How to Use CardLayout`, which was designed for this purpose.

Comment: When I first run the app, nothing is appeared at jframe. However, when i resize it, i was able to see loginPanel at center. Why did it happen ? I want to see it without resizing

Comment: ty 
these worked. I have a problem with design. I will work on it, ty ;)

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason to use `GridBagLayout`. This is a trivial thing to achieve
in `MigLayout`.

```
package com.zetcode;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

/*
Centering components in MigLayout manager.
Author: Jan Bodnar
Website: zetcode.com
 */
public class MigLayoutMoviesEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutMoviesEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("User name");
        JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Password:");

        JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Login");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Create user");

        createLayout(lbl1, field1, lbl2, field2, btn1, btn2);

        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("align 50% 50%"));

        add(arg[0]);
        add(arg[1], "wrap");
        add(arg[2]);
        add(arg[3], "wrap");
        add(arg[4]);
        add(arg[5]);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MigLayoutMoviesEx ex = new MigLayoutMoviesEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

To center the components, we use the `align 50% 50%` constraint.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the code example]